# Adding database retrieved data inside a for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm retrieving data from MySQL. All works fine.

My question is how do I add a for-loop correctly inside `function(data){ }`? Below is what I tried. But `data[0].color1` , `data[0].color2` , `data[0].color3` does not work inside the for-loop. How do I get the for-loop to work?

```
   var box = ['blk','red','yelw'];

    $.post('my.php',
        { stu:"Jamie" },
    function(data){
      for(i = 0; i<box.length; i++){
        $('#'+box[i]).text( data[0].color+i );
      }
    });
```

//this works (without a for loop)

```
  $('#blk').text(data[0].color1);
  $('#red').text(data[0].color2);
  $('#yelw').text(data[0].color3);
```

Comment: What does the console say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var box = ['blk','red','yelw'];

```
$.post('my.php',
    { stu:"Jamie" },
function(data){
  for(i = 0; i<box.length; i++){
    var c = 'color'+String(i);
    $('#'+box[i]).text( data[0][c] );
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks. looks good. Since the first value should be 1 (not 0), can I do this `var c = 'color' + String( i+1 );`

Comment: just do your for loop like this ...  for (i = 1; i <=box.length; i++)

Answer (score 0):

```
data[0].color+i
```

The above code does not get translated to what you think it is, you need to use

```
data[0]['color' + 1]
```

Comment: thank. very close. how do I get the first value as 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @Becky define `i=1` instead of `i=0` or just make a different variable like `j=1` and use that

Comment: @Mikey then it will skip the first one in the box array

Comment: @Becky edited my comment make a different variable for it and us that instead keeps it cleaner to work with also